# Not able to upload `.flv` - file(s) with ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular8, ng2-file-upload

Here is my mime types:

```
allowedMimeType = [
        'image/jpeg',
        'video/x-msvideo',
        'application/x-troff-msvideo',
        'video/avi',
        'video/msvideo',
        'video/x-msvideo',
        'application/x-shockwave-flash',
        'video/x-flv',
        'video/x-ms-wmv',
        'video/quicktime',
        'video/mp4',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'application/msword',
        'text/plain'
    ];
```

when i try to upload the `.flv` - files, getting error as `invalid file type`. what is wrong with my declaration? any one help me?

all other file types are working fine.

`this.fileUploader = new FileUploader(
            {
                allowedMimeType: this.allowedMimeType,
                maxFileSize: this.singleMaxFileSize,
                removeAfterUpload: true,
                queueLimit: 1
            }
        );`

Answer (score 0):

It's because of windows configuration. In the windows 10, `regedit` - `flv` is not added with `content-type` - after added it works.